# Change datasource of details view c#

Tags: c#

I have a project that has a details control with various text boxes along side a data grid view control. I have a refresh button which updates the data grid view. This is my code for this button:

```
string text = userIDLabel1.Text;
int currentUserID;
int.TryParse(text, out currentUserID);

//update datagridview
string dgvconn = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\n0740572\Projects\CW\CW\bin\Debug\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
string sql = "select * from Records where UserID = @CurrentUserID";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dgvconn);
SqlDataAdapter dataadapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
dataadapter2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentUserID", currentUserID);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
connection.Open();
dataadapter2.Fill(ds, "Records");
connection.Close();
recordsDataGridView.ReadOnly = true;
recordsDataGridView.DataSource = ds;
recordsDataGridView.DataMember = "Records";
```

Before I refresh the data grid view whenever I select a row, the details control text boxes automatically change to the values corresponding to the row chosen. However when I refresh the datagridview the details control textboxes no longer change. 
Is this because I am assigning the datagridview with a new data set / datasource and not doing the same to the details control?

Thanks for any help in advance,

Dan